# Отобразить список в активити

Tags: java, android, list

У меня в модели есть

```
List<Integer> products = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

И к ней прописаны геттеры и сеттеры:

```
public List<Integer> getProducts() {
    return products;
}

public void setProducts (List<Integer> products ) {
    this.products = products ;
}
```

Задача состоит в том, чтобы отобразить данные этого списка в моей активити.

К примеру чтобы сделать подобное для поля name, которое я также использую из модели я сделал следующее:
 1. Создал в xml поле

```
 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

2. Объявил в активити:

```
TextView name;
```

после чего нахожу данный элемент

```
TextView name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);
```

И отображаю его в активити:

```
name.setText(model.getName());
```

Comment: Что Вы подразумеваете под словом `объявить`? Что-то мне подсказывает, что у Вас какое-то свое, а не общепринятое определение этого понятия. Из-за этого вопрос становится непонятным.

Comment: @post_zeew отобразить) как я отобразил имя продукта)

Comment: А как вы хотите чтобы это выглядело?

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev ну пока мне не принципиально, к примеру name я объявил как простой TextView с параметрами по ширине и высоте) основная проблема для меня как потом возможно просэтить список. Главное чтоб он отображался в активити

Comment: Ну, если разницы нет, то `name.setText(model.getProducts());` должен устроить.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev в том и дело что не могу, пишет что не может реализовать метод setText(java.lang.String)

Comment: @Inkognito, `name.setText(model.getProducts().toString());`

Comment: @post_zeew работает только если в xml использовать `TextView` а я хочу списком, но он пишет что неподходящий тип для этого поля .

Comment: @Inkognito, Насколько я понял, каждый элемент списка, кроме прочего, включает в себя список. Вложенный список можно выводить в этот же `RecyclerView`, сделав для него несколько разных типов элементов.

Comment: @post_zeew у меня в первом списке айдишки, а в них уже как бы свои компонены, я хотел бы эти айдишки выводить списком если возможно. сейчас они выводятся как массив в [ 2313, 313 , 321]

Comment: @Inkognito, Я понял. В предыдущем моем комментарии я написал, как это реализовать.

Comment: А, можно еще проще. Сформируйте из списка айдишников строку. Добавляете первый айди, после него добавляете `\n`, добавляете второй айди, добавляете `\n`, и так далее. Потом эту строку выводите в `TextView`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, каждый элемент списка соответствует одному экземпляру класса `Model`, а этот класс, кроме прочего, содержит еще и некоторый список.

В классе `Model` реализуйте метод, который будет возвращать текстовое представление `ArrayList` в необходимом формате:

```
public String getProductsAsString() {
    if (products == null || products.isEmpty()) {
        return "";
    } else  {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i=0; i<products.size(); i++) {
            stringBuilder.append(products.get(i));
            if (i+1 != products.size()) {
                stringBuilder.append("\n");
            }
        }
        return stringBuilder.toString();
    }
}
```

И далее вызывайте его:

```
name.setText(model.getProductsAsString());
```

Если же Вам нужно, например, обрабатывать клики по элементам этого *подсписка*, то в адаптере для `RecyclerView` нужно создать еще один `ViewHolder`, который будет соответствовать элементу этого *подсписка*.

Comment: @Morozov, Покажите полностью файл модели с учетом добавления моего метода и код, в котором Вы этот метод вызываете. Вы сначала писали, что у Вас `List<Integer> products`, а теперь каким-то таинственным образом стало `View products`.

Comment: обновил вопрос. Вроде всё так как вы указали

Comment: @Inkognito, Переменная `kids` в методе `populateTextViews()` должна быть типа `TextView`.

Comment: поставил ListView, выводит красным метод 'setText' . Cannot resolve method 'java.lang.String'

Comment: @Inkognito, Зачем?!

Comment: вернул на TextView) вроде заработало корректно) спасибо за конструктивный ответ) прост игрался и так и этак и видимо что то упустил

Comment: + насколько правильно выносить данный метод в модель? не лучше ли его вынести в какой то класс Utils к примеру?

Comment: @Inkognito, Если этот метод используется где-то еще, можете вынести его куда-нибудь.